# Javascript files in Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I've tested my Rails app's functionality by placing jQuery at the bottom of my `home.html.erb` file with simple `script` tags.  Everything works fine until I attempt to utilize the Asset Pipleine in Rails 3.1 and place the script within `app/javascripts/home.js.erb`

Anyone know why I can't get the javascript to work outside of the home.html.erb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as what I was looking to do, which was separate javascript files for different views, I was unsuccessful.  I tried different naming conventions, etc.

What has worked for me however, is putting all of my javascript within `application.js`.  Doing this makes this code accessible by every view throughout the entire application.  Depending upon your needs and your app, you may want to put the script within `[your-model-name].js.coffee` which will make it accessible (I think just for your particular controllers and views).  Since my app is a single model/controller setup, this is essentially the same thing.

Then, it's a matter of using selectors carefully as to not interfere with other pages unintentionally.  In other words, if you want a piece of code to run within one particular view and not another, you will have to adjust your .js code accordingly, since everything within `application.js` is accessible to all views.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the script tag in the application.html.erb and you'll have jquery in all your pages. 
you can add the script in this way: (you should add the jquery-1.7.min file in the folder app/javascript)

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.min'%>
```

Comment: it's not an issue of having jquery on the app, im mostly talking about where to put my custom jQuery script...does that make sense? because (i think) jquery is loaded automatically on all rails 3.1 apps, right?

Comment: take a look a this link, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html. the visibility of your script depends of where you put it. lib/assets, app/assets or vendor/ assets

Comment: im pretty sure the manifest file line `//= require_tree .` adds all javascript files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

Don't put **home.js.erb** in **app/javascripts** but extract your jquery from **home.js.erb** and put in **app/assets/javascripts/home.js**

add   **config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )** to **config/environments/production.rb** or in **config/application.rb** for global env (test/dev/prod)

than in **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

call it with **javascript_include_tag "application"** from the view

... and finally, don't forget to add **gem 'jquery-rails'** to your **Gemfile** and run **bundle**